# Delete files if contents do not match pattern

Tags: files, sed, rm

There are hundreds of `.html` files in a directory. I need to delete files that don't contain word `bluecar` in their contents.

I thought *sed* with *rm* would do that, but I don't know how to combine them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using grep:

```
grep -L bluecar *.html | xargs rm
```

Comment: This not work for files with spaces in names.

Comment: This is easily fixed to work with filenames with spaces, at least with GNU tools: `grep -ZL bluecar *.html | xargs -0 rm`. I'd edit it in, but I see @php-coder already put in an answer with this...

Comment: won't this remove those that do contain `bluecar`?

Comment: @amphibient -L is --files-without-match

Answer (score 5):

With GNU grep/xargs you may use

```
grep -LZ -- str *.html | xargs -r0 rm
```

Answer (score 4):

The `find` tool is the usual one to use.

```
find . -name "*.html" \( -exec grep -q bluecar {} \; -o -exec rm {} \; \)
```

or

```
find . -name "*.html" ! -exec grep -q bluecar {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

But try it on a copy first...

Comment: Does this really take only arguments that returned a success code from the first exec and run them in the second or does it just run the full argument list through both execs?

Comment: @Caleb: Yes, `-exec` is true iff the command returns 0, and the `find` boolean operators short-circuit.

Comment: Is there some reason to use `-exec rm …` instead of `-delete`? `-delete` is generally much more efficient (saves a fork/exec per file).

Comment: @derobert No reason other than I'm not sure older versions of find have that action, and my habit of just using exec.